# Should I use a screensaver or just turn the monitor off when I am done?

Tags: display, power, screensaver

After using a screensaver for over ten years, I am starting to think about changing the way I save energy with my monitors.  I want to get in the habit of shutting my monitors off when I am done using the computer.  Right now, I just leave it sit, and after 15 minutes the screensaver comes on, and one hour after that the monitors power off.  I think I would use less overall power if I just shut them off when I am done.  Of course, I would have to get into the habit, which I think I can do.  My question is this:

Is there anything wrong with turning monitors on/off multiple times throughout the day?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A screensaver does not save power. In some cases, the screensaver can cause the computer to use MORE power (complex 3D screensavers).

Powering off modern monitors will not cause any detrimental harm to them.

If you want to save power, it is best to turn them off completely when you are not using them.

Comment: if you let windows 'turn off' the monitor, it will only go into stand-by and still consuming power. turn it off yourself.

Comment: Thanks!  I was planning to turn them off manually.  I can't wait to see that button get some wear-and-tear.  http://brighterplanet.com

Comment: speaking of 'wear and tear', i have a Dell flat panel and the silver layer on the power button is gone, instead of a fine green ring i now see a bright green LED, quite annoying, time to  do a paint job. :)

Comment: if you are going to be going on and off your computer constantly, then I would just let the screensaver run, as turning you monitor on/off all day could eventually cause more damage.

Comment: @TandemAdam Why does it cause more damage?

Comment: @Josh, turning a device on and off causes wear because the electronics expand and contract a little when they heat up and cool off. That can eventually lead to a failure.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to go nuts, plug it into a power strip and kill the power when you leave. It might still be drawing tiny power. I'm not sure about monitors. All those wall wart AC/DC converters draw power even when they aren't doing anything.